# Using getSelection only on a specific element instead of the whole Window/Document?

Tags: javascript, advanced-custom-fields, getselection

I am creating a sort of custom bookmarks feature which inserts the highlighted text into an ACF textarea field on a form once the modal button is clicked. This works, but the problem is the function seems to look in the whole document/window and is still running after, so clicking anywhere else gets rid of the inserted text. (Or if I highlight something else within the modal for example it pastes that instead). Please check this short 15 secs video to see what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAVQoTuMsCA

And this is the code I'm using:

https://snippi.com/s/h3h281w

I have that chapter variable at the top and I tried replacing window/document with chapter but I just get the following error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSelection') at HTMLDivElement.getSelectedText

Does anyone know how I can get this to only work on the area where the highlighted text is (#chapter) and not have it still happening after the text is inserted?

It was suggested to me to remove the event listener when the modal is open but I don't think I'm doing that right or the function itself is wrong.

Appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Unless there's more code going on that hasn't be included, this is pretty bizarre. Are you using jQuery? Because your conditional isn't even valid JS syntax `if(modal).hasClass('show')` you are missing the outer parens, and regular JS doesn't even have a method hasClass.

Comment: Hi. I'm not experienced in JS much at all to be honest so this is very much a case of me finding code online and testing it to see what works. So I was of course pleasantly surprised when the code did seem to work to some extent (the text is pasted in the right place) but obviously the issue remains of it continuing to run.

It is supposed to be jquery I believe. I did change the line to:

if(modal.hasClass('show')){

but then I get an error about modal.hasClass not being a function? 

Looking at what I'm trying to achieve do you know what the correct code should be please? Thanks.